# Different date/time values in 1 dataset

Tags: datetime, dataset, where-clause

I'm looking for a solution for the following case:

In this list I need to define 3 columns, 1 with a name , 1 with latest date/time sign on , 1 with latest date/time sign out.

FEX :

> Name | DATE  IN | DATE OUT
> TOM  | 25/08 | 27/08

I have a table with user information, and a table with the movements information, which I join.

To get the correct date for the date in, code looks like this

```
Select
Employee_name
max([Date Action]) as "Date IN",
From
[employee]  left join [Movement] .... 
where
[Move Type] = 0 ( = IN ) 
[Status] = 2 ( = Active )
Group by 
Employee_name;
```

How can I add the latest DATE OUT data to the dataset ?

> Where
>
> [Move type] = 1 ( =OUT )
>
> [Status] = 3

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement its pair as

```
Select
Employee_name
max([Date Action]) as "Date OUT",
From
[employee]  left join [Movement] .... 
where
[Move Type] = 1 ( = OUT ) 
[Status] = 2 ( = Active )
Group by 
Employee_name;
```

and `JOIN` the two together. In the RDBMSs I am used to it would look like

```
select t.Employee_name, t.[Date IN], t2.[Date OUT]
from
(
    Select
    Employee_name
    max([Date Action]) as "Date IN",
    From
    [employee]  left join [Movement] .... 
    where
    [Move Type] = 0 
    [Status] = 2
    Group by 
    Employee_name
) t
(    Select
    Employee_name
    max([Date Action]) as "Date OUT",
    From
    [employee]  left join [Movement] .... 
    where
    [Move Type] = 1 
    [Status] = 2
    Group by 
    Employee_name
) t2
on t.Employee_name = t2.Employee_name;
```